# Can not Run function when item selected in comboBox. Pyqgis. QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt

I'm writing a plugin, I want to change the content of a comboBox (fields) depending of the content of another comboBox (layers).

My plugin is a dockwidget. I can populate the fields comboBox just starting the plugin in the *def run(self):* function, and it's working fine:

```
        layerNom = self.dockwidget.comboBoxErrores.currentText()#Get the text value of the comboBox
        for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():    #Get layers        
            if lyr.name()==str(layerNom): 
                fields = lyr.pendingFields() #Get Fiels
                field_names = [field.name() for field in fields] #Field List
                self.dockwidget.comboCampos.addItems(field_names) #Added to the comboBox
```

But when I try to update the content of the fields comboBox I really don't know how to do it.

In my "pluginName_dockwidget.py" file, in the **init** function I have created the connection with the function that will repopulate the comboBox with the new content:

```
self.comboBoxErrores.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(self.pueblaCampos)
```

In the same file I have a function that get the value of the layer name of the comboBox and emit it with the signal created previously:

```
sennalComboIndex = pyqtSignal(str)
.
.
.
def pueblaCampos(self):      

    layerName = self.comboBoxErrores.currentText()
    self.sennalComboIndex.emit(layerName)
```

In my main file, I have the rest of the function:

```
def pueblaCampos(self, layerName):        

    for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if lyr.name()==str(layerName):
            fields = lyr.pendingFields()
            field_names = [field.name() for field in fields]             
            self.dockwidget.comboCampos.clear()
            self.dockwidget.comboCampos.addItems(field_names)
```

When I change the slected item in the layers comboBox, nothing happens. What Am I missing?

Comment: Are you calling the .connect signal in __init__() or initGui() function?

Comment: from __init__()

Comment: Try putting your .connect statements in the initGui() function instead to see if the signal is heard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, it was the only step I needed to make it run!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, add your .connect statements to the `initGui()` function.  This will allow the signal to be heard on whatever connect event.

Answer (score 2):

If you are programming in PyQGIS you should use **QgsMapLayerComboBox** and **QgsFieldComboBox** objects. It's easier and direct. For example, the next snipped code (from my plugin):

```
.
.
.
    def __init__(self, iface):
.
.
.
        okBtn = self.dlg.okButton
        okBtn.connect(okBtn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.my_function)

        self.wcbL = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self.dlg)
        self.wcbL.move(150,28)
        self.wcbL.setMinimumWidth(203)
        self.wcbL.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.VectorLayer)

        self.wcbF = QgsFieldComboBox(self.dlg)
        self.wcbF.move(150,68)
        self.wcbF.setMinimumWidth(203)
.
.
.
    def select_layer_fields(self, vlayer):

        self.wcbF.setLayer(vlayer)
        field = self.wcbF.setLayer(vlayer)

    def my_function(self):

        vlayer = self.wcbL.currentLayer()
        field = self.wcbF.currentText()
        print field

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        vlayer = self.wcbL.currentLayer()
        self.wcbF.setLayer(vlayer)
        self.wcbL.layerChanged.connect(self.select_layer_fields)

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
.
.
.
```

it can do the work. I tried out with the following three vector layers:

[image]

After selecting **polygon8** vector layer, you can observe that the fields from its attributes table are the same that into the **QgsFieldComboBox** object.

[image]

After selecting **polygon5** vector layer, the fields automatically change to show those of this new layer; as it can be observed in the next image:

[image]

To corroborate that it works well, the slot **my_function** (connected to OK button) has an instruction to **print** the reference of the fields at the Python Console of QGIS after clicking the OK button. It could be observed for fields 'area' and 'values' of **polygon8** at the next image:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your complete and useful answer!! I'm going to try it as an alternative!

Answer (score 0):

In order to clear what I did, I'm going to reply myself. I just needed a line that connect the signal emited from the `pluginName_dockwidget.py` file to `pluginName.py` in the `initGui()` function.

this is the line:

```
self.dockwidget.sennalComboIndex.connect(self.pueblaCampos)
```